# How to set the percentage in screen of each fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to design a divided screen into two non equal parts in a landscape mode of screen. So, I thought automatically in using fragments. But the problem that I have encountered is that each fragment match the half of the screen. And that's not what I want exactly. What I want is a screen with two parts non equal in their width. I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: post what u tried till

Comment: Weights were introduced for exactly what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the **weight** parameter.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please notice the weights used for the two LinearLayouts. The first one has a weight of 1 (it can occupy 1/4 th of the screen) and the second one 3 (it can occupy 3/4 th of the screen).

Just use this exact same concept for your fragments and maintain nay proportion as you wish.

Hope I could make myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use weight parameter

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="3" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: fill_parent was deprecated since sdk 8. Please use match_parent

Answer (score 0):

set Linear layout **weight** to achieve this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```